# Is there an equivalent to maven/ivy dependency management for python?

Tags: java, python, dependencies

Is there an equivalent to maven/ivy dependency management for python?   I mean, something that will automatically download all my dependencies based on a simple specification (as is done for java ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: this is a tough one :) I have been googling for one but  not sure.  Saw something about "fabricate" online... I hope someone can answer this !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html (Requirements files)

http://www.buildout.org/

Comment: PIP is very effective for grabbing deps.  Thanks     that s what i needed

Answer (score 0):

I know about [Pip](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pip&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEUQFjAD&url=http://www.pip-installer.org/&ei=tcOtTo6JN4TLtAb5pbD7Aw&usg=AFQjCNHw6u7gTzYi0tBn5EY4mJZ7dWZUBQ), that uses a very [simple text format for requirements specification](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html).